# Pydio Cells docker + NGINX = 404 error on /ws/chat and /ws/event

Tags: docker, nginx, websocket, cell, pydio

I have set up a Docker container using the `pydio/cells:2.1.1` image from dockerhub.

My `docker-compose.yaml` contains the following section:

```
cells:
    image: pydio/cells:2.1.1
    environment:
     - CELLS_NO_TLS=1
     - CELLS_BIND=files.redacted.dev:8080
     - CELLS_EXTERNAL=https://files.redacted.dev
    volumes:
     - /srv/cells:/var/cells
    ports:
     - "8081:8080"
    depends_on:
     - cells_mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
```

To expose Cells to the network I'm using NGINX with the following configuration:

```
server {

    client_max_body_size 200M;
    server_name files.redacted.dev;

    location / {
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /ws {
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/files.redacted.dev/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/files.redacted.dev/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = files.redacted.dev) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name files.redacted.dev;

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Pretty much everything works OK however I noticed that when I create a new file or folder I then had to reload before it appeared in the UI.

Looking at Firefox's dev console I see 404 errors on GET `wss://files.redacted.dev/ws/chat` and `wss://files.redacted.dev/ws/event` requests.

I tested on the host with the following command (thereby bypassing NGINX):

```
curl --include --no-buffer --header "Connection: Upgrade" --header "Upgrade: websocket" --header "Host: files.redacted.dev:80" --header "Origin: https://files.redacted.dev" --header "Sec-WebSocket-Key: SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==" --header "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" http://localhost:8081/ws/chat
```

And the command didn't terminate (I'm assuming that means it was successful...).

Looks like the NGINX configuration is the problem. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it was a missing header for the /ws location:

```
location /ws {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    proxy_set_header Host $host; # This is what was missing!
    proxy_http_version 1.1; # This might also be needed...
}
```